# Position sticky to bottom of scrollable element

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a footer to stick to the bottom of a scrollable block element. It only works if the content (table in this case) is greater than the container height. How do I always get the the footer to stick to the bottom?

I tried using `position: absolute` instead, but that stays fixed when the user scrolls.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the table always have a fixed height of 150px? Or will it be variable?

Comment: Please add the code from your JSFiddle directly into the question - you can create a runnable Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` button on the question toolbar to do this. External links are discouraged here as they can change or break over time, making your question unhelpful to future users if they can't see the code :)

Comment: @evilgenious448 I suppose max-height could be used instead to solve the issue, but the height needs to be fixed.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Done :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the display of the `.container` to flex

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

And the `.footer` needs to have a `margin-top: auto;`

See code here:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

In this example the footer takes up the entire width of the container, however that is easy to fix in the styling if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can use a `flex-box` in combination with a scrollable `content` element. Using `flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;` the last child of the `content` element will always be positioned at the bottom.

**Edit:** I assumed that you want to have a fixed content `height`. But this also works with dynamic heights. For this you have to change the `height: 150px;` property to `max-height` property.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content__item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
   <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
   <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you can use sticky and fixed on any elements, regardless of where they are nested.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my answer. Never saw this combination before.

Comment: In your solution the footer is outside the scroll bar, which is an interesting approach. Not sure if it is what the OP is after, but a possible solution to his problem.